# How to infere a type from a generic type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript

I know the title might confusing, but I didn't know how to put it.

The thing is, I have a React component that receives an array of objects with the key/values of an input, like this:

`[{id: 'my-input', label: 'my input', defaultValue: 'foo'}, ...and so on]`

The label value is custom of course, because I'm extending the `InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>` interface.

Now, what I do when an Input changes is pass that value to a state called formData, that looks like this:

```
{
    myInput1: 'value',
    myInput2: 'anotherValue',
    myCheckbox: false,
    myOtherCheckbox: true
}
```

And finally, the submit function. I think it explains itself if I just write it:

```
<Form
    onSubmit={(data) => mySubmitFunction(data)}
    id='my-form'
    inputs={formInputs}
/>
```

I define the `data` param in the FormProps interface to be like `{[key: string]: BaseInput['value'] | BaseInput['checked']}`, which is fine, but I want it to do something better. I want the data param to infere that every key should be an input label (or if it isn't specified, use the id), and the value should be that input value type, so if I do something like:

```
<Form
    onSubmit={(data) => mySubmitFunction(data)}
    id='my-form'
    inputs={[
        {
            id: 'input-1',
            type: 'text',
        },
        {
            id: 'input-2',
            label: 'myInputCheck',
            type: 'checkbox'
        }
    ]}
/>
```

The data param should look like this:

```
data: {
    'input-1': string, // it knows that I didn't specify a label, so it takes the id instead
    myInputCheck: boolean
}
```

The chain of events is like this:

First, I call the component:

```
const myInputs: FormInputs = [
    {
        id: 'text',
        type: 'text',
        key: createStr(),
    },
    {
        id: 'number',
        type: 'number',
        key: createStr(),
    },
    {
        id: 'radio',
        type: 'radio',
        key: createStr(),
    },
    {
        id: 'checkbox',
        type: 'checkbox',
        key: createStr(),
    },
]

<Form
    onSubmit={(data) => mySubmitFunction(data)}
    id='form-maker'
    inputs={myInputs}
/>
```

Then, inside the component (the bussiness logic)

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { FormData, FormProps } from '../../interfaces'

const useForm = ({ id: myFormID, inputs }: Omit<FormProps, 'onSubmit'>) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState<FormData>({})
    const formID = `form__${myFormID}`

    const onInputChange = (key: string, value: any) =>
        setFormData({ ...formData, [key]: value })

    const getInputValue = (
        {
            type,
            value,
            defaultValue = '',
            checked,
            defaultChecked = false,
        }:
            | typeof inputs[0]
            | typeof inputs[1]
            | (EventTarget & HTMLInputElement),
        useDefault?: boolean
    ) => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'checkbox':
            case 'radio':
                return useDefault ? defaultChecked : checked
            default:
                return useDefault ? defaultValue : value
        }
    }

    const createFormData = () => {
        const newFormData = cloneDeep(formData)

        inputs.forEach((input) => {
            newFormData[input.id] = getInputValue(input, true)
        })

        setFormData(newFormData)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        createFormData()
    }, [])

    return { formID, onInputChange, getInputValue, formData }
}

export default useForm
```

- When the component mounts, it creates the formData state from the inputs array, givin it its default value/checked and rendering the Form component using the inputs array (nothing relevant, just rendering from that array so you don't need to see that). >>>
- Then, when an input changes, it sets its value/checked to the formData state. >>>
- Then, when the form submits `onSubmit={() => onSubmit(formData)}` it just calls the 'onSubmit' function passed when I call the component, with the formData arg, so I can do stuff with that data.

Here, the interfaces:

```
// I rewrite this one because I want to specifically use those and nothing else
type BaseInputType =
    | 'button'
    | 'checkbox'
    | 'color'
    | 'date'
    | 'datetime-local'
    | 'email'
    | 'file'
    | 'hidden'
    | 'image'
    | 'month'
    | 'number'
    | 'password'
    | 'radio'
    | 'range'
    | 'reset'
    | 'search'
    | 'submit'
    | 'tel'
    | 'text'
    | 'time'
    | 'url'
    | 'week'

interface BaseInput
    extends Omit<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'id' | 'type'> {
    id: string
    key: string
    label?: string
    type: BaseInputType
}

interface InputSelect extends Omit<BaseInput, 'type'> {
    type: 'select'
    options: SelectOption[]
}

type FormInputs = (BaseInput | InputSelect)[]

interface FormData {
    [key: string]: BaseInput['value'] | BaseInput['checked']
}

interface FormProps
    extends Omit<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, 'id' | 'onSubmit'> {
    id: string
    inputs: FormInputs
    onSubmit: (data: FormData) => void
}
```

I hope I made myself clear: I want Typescript to take the inputs array I pass to the Form, and on the formData state, specifically on the submit function, infere every key/type pair based on the inputs array I first passed.

If and only if possible, I'd like to be able to transform the key to camelCase. I have a function that does just that, but I don't know if I can use it inside an interface or something like that, or if in the chain of events I can call it and typescript will know that the output will be camelCased.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, you want the compile-time-available types to be based on something that could be known only at runtime, since technically the data object being passed as `inputs` - is a complete dynamic thing. That is logically NOT possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. Sometimes I pass a dynamic value, but in this particular case my data is written in my code directly, that's why I thought maybe there was a way for typescript to do all that logic for me so when I submit the form (with hardcoded inputs) I already know what the data keys would look like and what their value type will be. I hope I make myself clear.